# Deploy packages to multiple webapp service by azure pipeline single stage

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I have more than 100 webapp service in azure. I want to deploy packages in 100 webapps by azure pipeline with one pipeline yml file. But I couldn't find any documentation like this. I got one microsoft documentation and they prefer to increase pipeline steps. If I have 100 webapps service, then have to add 100 steps for each deployment. This is not an efficient way and its time consuming. I want just like this step.

```
- task: AzureWebApp@1
  displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(Parameters.connectedServiceName)'
    appType: webApp
    ResourceGroupName: $(group)
    appName: 'JustGoTestAgain, justgotesttwo, webapp123, webapp555, webapp777 and so on ........'
    package: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

This yaml file is showing error. I couldn't find any essential extensions to fix it. I also couldn't find any azure powershell deployment command regarding to this issue. How can I get the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to do this like this. However you can use [Azure Cli task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops):

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Azure CLI
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(Parameters.connectedServiceName)'
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |

      $apps= @('JustGoTestAgain, justgotesttwo, webapp123, webapp555, webapp777 and so on ........')

      foreach ($app in $apps) {
         az webapp deployment source config-zip -g $(group) -n $app --src '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/SOME_FOLDER/Artifact.zip'
      }
```

And here you have more details about deployment [itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_deployment_source_config_zip)

Annother approach with multiple task bu continuation if one fail is:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: apps
  type: object
  default:
    - JustGoTestAgain
    - justgotesttwo
    - and so on

steps:
- ${{ each app in parameters.apps}}:
  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy ${{ app }}'
    continueOnError: true
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '$(Parameters.connectedServiceName)'
      appType: webApp
      ResourceGroupName: $(group)
      appName: ${{ app }}
      package: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

Thete was issue with space. Now is fine. Apart from that there is only one issue with `connectedServiceName`

> Job Job: Step input azureSubscription references service connection $(Parameters.connectedServiceName) which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz. Job Job: Step input azureSubscription references service connection $(Parameters.connectedServiceName) which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz. Job Job: Step input azureSubscription references service connection $(Parameters.connectedServiceName) which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.

Which I skipped here as you already have it on your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help but sorry to say that none of your two answer worked. I got same previous error from your first answer. 

**ERROR: (ResourceNotFound) The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/JustGoTestAgain, justgotesttwo' under resource group 'Cybertron' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
##[error]Script failed with exit code: 1**

Second one is showing mapping problem with - ${{ each app in parameters.apps}}: this line. I tried to fix it by following microsoft document but the appName is not taking multiple value.

Comment: Make sure you have app in `Cybertron`, or you use correct names - resource group and app name. I can't help more here since I don't have access to your Azure subscription. For the second `     appName: ${{ app }}` will take only one app name and that's it. It will create as many ` - task: AzureWebApp@1` tasks as you have apps provide but it will still take only one app as argument.